# Correct way to offer NULL value in ASP Select control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a User class that *might* be assigned to a Company class. The FK in the ASPNetUser table is nullable, of type uniquidentifier (from ASPNet template), this matches fine with the foreign table and I can insert fine providing I select a valid Company.

I bring the the list of companies down and populate a `<select>` control like this:

```
<select asp-for="CompanyID" asp-items="Model.Companies" class="dropdown form-control">
    <option value="" selected>--None--</option>
</select>
```

What do I need to put in the **value** attribute to pass a null through? Or is it better done in the `SelectItemList`?

Comment: Unclear what your asking. What you doing will post a `null` value for `CompanyID` if you select the first (`"--None--"`) option.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to populate your data like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyID, Model.Companies,"--Select a Company--")

Companies = new SelectList(_db.Companies, "CompanyID", "Name");
```

Comment: I could do - but I was under the assumption that the TagHelpers would replace this. Is this not the case?

Comment: They are not ignoring each other when used together.